# Nested SQL Query in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[enter image description here][1]Below is my nested query that runs on my database. Is the same nested query can run in spark scala.

```
select std.studentid, std.fname, std.lname
from student std
where std.studentid not in (select gr.studentid sid
from grade gr
left join section sc on sc.sectionno = gr.sectionno
and sc.courseno = gr.courseno
and sc.instructor = 'King'
where sc.sectionno is NOT NULL);
```

My question is that I am using two select statement one is nested in other. How can I run this type of queries in Spark SqlContext. If I run SQL statement in spark-shell CLI with just one select statement it works fine but when I run nested SQL query with two select statements as shown in my example, it gives me error.

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("SELECT *   from dfs").show
+---------------+---------------+------+-------+--------+---+-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+
|          srcIp|         destIp|srcPrt|destPrt|protocol|TTL|payload|       seq|  win|fin|syn|rst|push|ack|urg|ece|cwr|
+---------------+---------------+------+-------+--------+---+-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+
| 131.183.222.85|131.183.222.110|  5632|  63715|       6| 64|  41452| 130035785|18689|  0|  0|  0|   1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
| 131.183.222.85|131.183.222.110|  5632|  63715|       6| 64|  12780| 922877389|24833|  0|  0|  0|   0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
| 131.183.222.85|  136.247.82.83| 63715|   5632|      17| 64|  12780| 922877389|24833|  0|  0|  0|   0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|   43.230.146.7| 131.183.222.85| 18570|  21958|       6| 64|  12780| 544309034|58624|  0|  0|  0|   0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|131.183.222.110| 131.183.222.85| 63715|   5632|       6| 64|  23276| 544309034|58624|  0|  0|  0|   1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
| 131.183.222.85|  136.247.82.83| 63715|   5632|      17| 64|  10737| 143622358|62464|  0|  0|  0|   1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|   43.230.146.7| 131.183.222.85| 18570|  21958|       6| 64|  25068|1620345046|  769|  0|  0|  0|   1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
+---------------+---------------+------+-------+--------+---+-------+----------+-----+---+---+---+----+---+---+---+---+
```

Error In query

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("SELECT *   from dfs where dfs.destIp in (select srcIp from dfs)").show
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Unsupported language features in query: SELECT *   from dfs where dfs.destIp in (select srcIp from dfs)
TOK_QUERY 1, 0,26, 16
  TOK_FROM 1, 6,8, 16
    TOK_TABREF 1, 8,8, 16
      TOK_TABNAME 1, 8,8, 16
        dfs 1, 8,8, 16
  TOK_INSERT 0, -1,26, 0
    TOK_DESTINATION 0, -1,-1, 0
      TOK_DIR 0, -1,-1, 0
        TOK_TMP_FILE 0, -1,-1, 0
    TOK_SELECT 0, 0,2, 0
      TOK_SELEXPR 0, 2,2, 0
        TOK_ALLCOLREF 0, 2,2, 0
    TOK_WHERE 1, 10,26, 37
      TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR 1, 12,26, 37
        TOK_SUBQUERY_OP 1, 16,16, 37
          in 1, 16,16, 37
        TOK_QUERY 1, 18,26, 59
          TOK_FROM 1, 23,25, 59
            TOK_TABREF 1, 25,25, 59
              TOK_TABNAME 1, 25,25, 59
                dfs 1, 25,25, 59
          TOK_INSERT 0, -1,21, 0
            TOK_DESTINATION 0, -1,-1, 0
              TOK_DIR 0, -1,-1, 0
                TOK_TMP_FILE 0, -1,-1, 0
            TOK_SELECT 1, 19,21, 48
              TOK_SELEXPR 1, 21,21, 48
                TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 21,21, 48
                  srcIp 1, 21,21, 48
        . 1, 12,14, 29
          TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 12,12, 26
            dfs 1, 12,12, 26
          destIp 1, 14,14, 30

scala.NotImplementedError: No parse rules for ASTNode type: 864, text: TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR :
TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR 1, 12,26, 37
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: My question is that I am using two select statement one is nested in other. How can I run this type of queries in Spark SqlContext. If I run SQL statement in spark-shell CLI with just one  select statement it works fine but when I run nested SQL query with two select statements as shown in my example, it gives me error.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: please see the updated question with both running query and query with error.

Comment: @zero323, Thanks for your comment. It was helpful

Comment: Sure. If it answers your question please accept duplicate vote. And don't forget to upvote another one :)